# VPN pre command script for Remmina

Tags: bash, scripts, vpn, remmina

I am trying to find a way to start a VPN pre command script prior to opening my RDP session in Remmina. I am only able to connect to my PPP vpn via the terminal, but can't figure out how to get it working via the desktop. It is doing my head in. I have tried the following:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -lc "pon vpn ;bash"'

" #!/bin/bash pppd call vpn "

ssh -t user@server "sudo pon vpn && exit"
```

I have set the above up as executable scripts and like I said, am able to execute via the terminal, or even just by running command pon vpn or pppd call vpn.

Has anyone accomplished this, why can't I find anything online about this? Surely there are others that connect first to a VPN and then RDP. I am able to accomplish a lot of this sort of stuff with mRemoteNG in windows, with pre and post batch scripts. Just want to figure it out with linux (I am using ubuntu).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out. If anyone is wanting to do the same, here is how to get it working.

First install SSH pass. This allows you to pass a password to a remote SSH session

In the terminal type the following:

```
apt-get install sshpass
```

[This guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-ubuntu-fedora-linux-pptp-client.html) will walk you through setting up PPTP connections via the terminal.

Once you have setup your VPN client connection, you will need to create a Remmina pre-command script. This script will establish a VPN connection prior to RDP'ing or SSH'ing onto your remote server.

Create the script in `/usr/local/bin` to make it accessible to all users. Make the script executable.

Script name example: VPNConnect.sh

```
> #! /bin/bash
> 
> echo 'Connecting to VPN...'
> 
> sshpass -p "Password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server
> 'sudo killall pppd; sudo pppd call vpn; sleep 5 && exit'
```

This script is essentially SSH'ing into a remote shell and starting the VPN connection. I couldn't get it to work any other way. The last part of the script is telling it to sleep, or wait for 5 seconds. This part is important, if you don't put it there Remmina will run the pre-command script too quickly before the VPN is established and you won't be able to RDP in.

The Post-Command script is just disconnecting from VPN connection.

Script name example: VPNDisconnect.sh

```
> #! /bin/bash
> 
> echo 'Disconnecting from VPN...'
> 
> sshpass -p "Password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server
> "sudo killall pppd && exit"
```

It's awesome that Remmina allows you to run pre and post command scripts. Just was difficult finding any documentation on any examples online.